# sync collection without replica set

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've got two servers, one does a lot of data processing (local), the other one(remote) makes the data available for other use.

I'd like to update the remote collection using JavaScript/Node.js. Is there a way to only update items that need to be updated without matching individual records?

Comment: Are you going to do `write` operations only in the remote server? Are you planning to reconcile the difference back to the local server at some point ?

Comment: ah yes, it is a one-way operation. Local is always correct, remote is having collection docs added or replaced based on data in local

Comment: You could tail MongoDB oplog to track changes of local. This is (sort of) the method that is used by Meteor : [Oplog and Meteor](https://meteorhacks.com/mongodb-oplog-and-meteor/).  Since you are using Node.Js, see [Node.Js MongoDB Oplog](https://www.compose.io/articles/the-mongodb-oplog-and-node-js/) . See also [Pitfalls and workarounds for tailing the oplog](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/pitfalls-and-workarounds-for-tailing-the-oplog-on-a-mongodb-sharded-cluster)

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it. It did give me an idea to timestamp last change. I would then push all data `>=` last date synced. I may also end up just pushing aggregated data, since I do know what kind of data I will be querying for.

Comment: The oplog is akin to CQRS/Event sourcing design, where only updates/modifications are stored with timestamps. This is useful if you want to see the state in a point in time (history).